# Ajax CAML Query 400 Bad Request

Tags: caml-query, ajax, soap

I get a 400 bad request with this ajax call, i tryied the caml query with caml designer and it should work. What is the problem?

```
        var soapEnv = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>";
            soapEnv += "    <soapenv:Body>";
            soapEnv += "        <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>";
            soapEnv += "      <listName>PollUserData</listName>";
            soapEnv += "      <query>";
            soapEnv += "        <Query>";
            soapEnv += "              <OrderBy Override='TRUE'>";
            soapEnv += "                  <FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='FALSE' />";
            soapEnv += "              </OrderBy>";   
            soapEnv += "          <Where>";
            soapEnv += "            <And>";
            soapEnv += "               <Eq>";
            soapEnv += "                   <FieldRef Name='UserID' />"
            soapEnv += "                   <Value Type='Text'>" + userGuid + "</Value>";
            soapEnv += "              </Eq>";
            soapEnv += "               <Eq>";
            soapEnv += "                   <FieldRef Name='QuestionID' />"
            soapEnv += "                   <Value Type='Text'>" + allQuestionsArray[i].ID + "</Value>";
            soapEnv += "              </Eq>";
            soapEnv += "           </And>";*/
            soapEnv += "       </Where>";
            soapEnv += "     </Query>";
            soapEnv += "    </query>";
            soapEnv += "      </viewFields>";
            soapEnv += "       <ViewFields>";
            soapEnv += "         <FieldRef Name='UserID'/>";
            soapEnv += "         <FieldRef Name='QuestionID'/>";
            soapEnv += "         <FieldRef Name='Question'/>";
            soapEnv += "         <FieldRef Name='Answer'/>";
            soapEnv += "       </ViewFields>";
            soapEnv += "      </viewFields>";
            soapEnv += "    </GetListItems>";
            soapEnv += "  </soapenv:Body>";
            soapEnv += " </soapenv:Envelope>";

            var port = window.location.port;
            if (port.length <= 0)
                port = "";
            else
                port = ":" + port;
            var webservice = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";

            $.ajax({
              url: webservice,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            async: false,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
            complete: function (xData, status) {
                $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function () {
            })
            }, error: function(xhr){
            }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a closing tag at the beginning of the viewFields Block :

```
        soapEnv += "      </viewFields>";
        soapEnv += "       <ViewFields>";
        soapEnv += "         <FieldRef Name='UserID'/>";
        soapEnv += "         <FieldRef Name='QuestionID'/>";
        soapEnv += "         <FieldRef Name='Question'/>";
        soapEnv += "         <FieldRef Name='Answer'/>";
        soapEnv += "       </ViewFields>";
        soapEnv += "      </viewFields>";
```

replace by

```
        soapEnv += "      <viewFields>";
        soapEnv += "       <ViewFields>";
        soapEnv += "         <FieldRef Name='UserID'/>";
        soapEnv += "         <FieldRef Name='QuestionID'/>";
        soapEnv += "         <FieldRef Name='Question'/>";
        soapEnv += "         <FieldRef Name='Answer'/>";
        soapEnv += "       </ViewFields>";
        soapEnv += "      </viewFields>";
```

Which version of SP are you using ? Why do you have mutiple enclosed tags?

Comment: Thank you, that did the work. I am using multiple enclosed tags becouse of soap.